# Outlook failing to sync with Exchange Server (Error 0x8004010F)

Tags: exchange, outlook

A small number of clients can't sync their postbox with exchange (2013). When they try to do it outlook (2016) will throw an 0x8004010F error saying that it "Can't find Object" but doesn't say which object. In fact there is no communication with the server at all. Using wireshark I did find out that outook is trying to resolve the SRV Entry for _autodiscover._tcp.domainname.xyz which succeeds but even with that information no communication happens at all.
The same clients can download their mails through POP3 or IMAP without any problem at all. So it seems to be some kind of MAPI issue.

I tried all kinds of things but nothing seems to work. I did try to fix the .ost file. (Which wasn't corrupt). I did create new profiles, did a repair installation of office and did follow the microsoft documentation regarding that failure. (which seemed to focus more on this version of the error which regards the missing local file).

// These problems seem to be tied to specific hosts. The affected users are able to use their accounts on other hosts.

Answer (score 1):

**Note: -** Since OAB (offline address book) used Microsoft outlook client in Cached Exchange Mode for address book lookups when offline and it also reduces the workload of the server.

**Error 0x8004010F error occur when:**

**1)** Users can't download the Offline Address Book.
**2)** Synchronization errors occur in the Offline Address Book.
**3)** You receive nondelivery report (NDR) messages when you use the Offline
**4)** Address Book to send email messages to users.
**5)** OST file is unavailable or corrupted.
**6)** Multiple OAB file version exists of the same type.
**8)** When a profile is incorrectly configured.
**9)** Object is either missing or incorrect in OAB file list.

Since this 0x8004010F error can occur due to various reason, hence various solution can be available such as:

**a)** Global address list (GAL) is up to date
**b)** Cached Exchange Mode is enabled
**c)** Background Intelligence Transfer Service (BITS) service is running
**d)** Autodiscover service is working, and check access to the Offline Address Book

Go for [Post](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/2429946/how-to-troubleshoot-the-outlook-offline-address-book-in-an-office-365) for step by step solution for the different method, hope any solution works for you. 
To know about the error [0x8004010F](http://www.edbtopstpro.com/blog/exchange-server/exchange-error-0x8004010f.html) and solution.

Answer (score 0):

Only occurs on some special mailbox (with multiple Outlook client)?
How about OWA?

Try to move [**those mailboxes to other DB**](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj150487(v=exchg.150).aspx) (**repair broken mailbox content**), then try again.